# How do I get a list of column data from an array into a list in flutter (dart)

Tags: flutter, dart

I've been trying to get a column from a array into a list, I'm can't seem to figure how to do it, and I couldn't find a solution online. Most of the array i find only aren't nested.

```
{
  "status": true,
  "data": {
    "1": [
      {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "500MB [SME]",
        "price": "220",
        "telco_price": "0"
      },
      {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "1GB [SME]",
        "price": "410",
        "telco_price": "0"
      },
      {
        "id": "3",
        "name": "2GB [SME]",
        "price": "800",
        "telco_price": "0"
      },
      
    ],
    "2": [
      {
        "id": "AIR1000",
        "name": "1.5GB ",
        "price": "920",
        "telco_price": "920"
      },
      {
        "id": "AIR2000",
        "name": "4.5GB",
        "price": "1840",
        "telco_price": "1840"
      },
      {
        "id": "AIR2500",
        "name": "6GB",
        "price": "2300",
        "telco_price": "2300"
      }
    ],
    "3": [
      {
        "id": "9MOB500",
        "name": "500MB",
        "price": "400",
        "telco_price": "400"
      },
      {
        "id": "9MOB1000",
        "name": "1.5GB",
        "price": "850",
        "telco_price": "850"
      },
      {
        "id": "9MOB2000",
        "name": "2GB",
        "price": "1020",
        "telco_price": "1020"
      },
    ]
  }
}
```

firstly, i want to get all names into a list variable which i can then populate easily on one of my page...
i want it into `var nameList = [];` where its' stated "1" then the next into another variable like that

Comment: Are you using any model class

Comment: I'm just calling it inside a function

Comment: is that a json response or variable?

Comment: It's a json response

Comment: Do you like to have initial value or just data inside {}

Comment: no initial value, just that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do on fetch like

```dart
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
....
 List<DataClass> nameList = [];

  fetch() async {
    final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      final data = jsonDecode(response.body);
      MyResponse myResponse = MyResponse.fromJson(data);

      final values = myResponse.data?.values;

      if (values != null) {
        for (final v in values) {
         if(v!=null) nameList.addAll(v.toList());
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Try this model class

```dart
import 'dart:convert';

class MyResponse {
  final bool? status;

  final Map<String, List<DataClass>?>? data;
  MyResponse({
    this.status,
    required this.data,
  });

  

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    final result = <String, dynamic>{};
  
    if(status != null){
      result.addAll({'status': status});
    }
    if(data != null){
      result.addAll({'data': data});
    }
  
    return result;
  }

  factory MyResponse.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    return MyResponse(
      status: map['status'],
      data: Map<String, List<DataClass>?>.from(map['data']),
    );
  }

  String toJson() => json.encode(toMap());

  factory MyResponse.fromJson(String source) => MyResponse.fromMap(json.decode(source));
}

class DataClass {
  final String? id;
  final String? name;
  final String? price;
  final String? telco_price;
  DataClass({
    this.id,
    this.name,
    this.price,
    this.telco_price,
  });

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    final result = <String, dynamic>{};

    if (id != null) {
      result.addAll({'id': id});
    }
    if (name != null) {
      result.addAll({'name': name});
    }
    if (price != null) {
      result.addAll({'price': price});
    }
    if (telco_price != null) {
      result.addAll({'telco_price': telco_price});
    }

    return result;
  }

  factory DataClass.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    return DataClass(
      id: map['id'],
      name: map['name'],
      price: map['price'],
      telco_price: map['telco_price'],
    );
  }

  String toJson() => json.encode(toMap());

  factory DataClass.fromJson(String source) =>
      DataClass.fromMap(json.decode(source));
}
```